# How to use javascript class from within document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I have this countdown script wrapped as an object located in a separate file

**Then when I want to setup a counter, the timeout function in the countdown class can not find the object again that I have setup within the document ready.**

I sort of get that everything that is setup in the document ready is convined to that scope,
however it is possible to call functions within other document ready´s.

**Does anyone has a solution on how I could setup multiple counters slash objects.
Or do those basic javascript classes have to become plugins**

This is the class

```
  function countdown(obj)
{
    this.obj        = obj;
    this.Div        = "clock";
    this.BackColor      = "white";
    this.ForeColor      = "black";
    this.TargetDate     = "12/31/2020 5:00 AM";
    this.DisplayFormat  = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
    this.CountActive    = true;

    this.DisplayStr;

    this.Calcage        = cd_Calcage;
    this.CountBack      = cd_CountBack;
    this.Setup      = cd_Setup;
}

function cd_Calcage(secs, num1, num2)
{
  s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
  if (s.length < 2) s = "0" + s;
  return (s);
}
function cd_CountBack(secs)
{
  this.DisplayStr = this.DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g,    this.Calcage(secs,86400,100000));
  this.DisplayStr = this.DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g,       this.Calcage(secs,3600,24));
  this.DisplayStr = this.DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g,       this.Calcage(secs,60,60));
  this.DisplayStr = this.DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g,       this.Calcage(secs,1,60));

  //document.getElementById(this.Div).innerHTML = this.DisplayStr;

  $('#'+this.Div).text(this.DisplayStr);
  $('#tel').text(parseInt( $('#tel').text() )+1);


  if (this.CountActive) setTimeout(this.obj +".CountBack(" + (secs-1) + ")", 990);
}
function cd_Setup()
{
    var dthen   = new Date(this.TargetDate);
    var dnow    = new Date();
    ddiff       = new Date(dthen-dnow);
    gsecs       = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
    this.CountBack(gsecs);
}
```

and setting it up

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var cd1 = new countdown('cd1');
  cd1.Div = "clk";
 cd1.TargetDate = "08/15/2010 8:00 PM";
  cd1.DisplayFormat = "%%D%% days, %%H%% hours, %%M%% minutes, %%S%% seconds until event   AAA happens"; 
 cd1.Setup();
```

firebug says it errors out with the timeout function

thanks, Richard

Comment: , the information you have given us provides no usable context for us members to help you.  You might as well have posted saying "My program doesn't work.  Help.".  And i'm not trying to be disrespectful or anything, honestly.  Us SO members have no idea what "this" is defined as in your program?  In the current moment, I think that `this == window` would evaluate to true?

Comment: sorry, just a sec, I will post the whole thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cd1 is defined in the local scope.  setTimeout will run the function passed as parameter 1 in the window [global] scope, and in your case, window.cd1 is undefined.

The solution for your problem would to make cd1 a global variable.  [Remove the "var" in your declaration of cd1]

---

Off topic: I recommend you look into using anonymous functions, as they can make your code much more pretty/legible at times.

Comment: I diddn´t know that about var, thanks
I am looking at the jquery plugin counters page
If yoy could suggest one that will be great, I only need to count up until the next ajax call.If not thats ok too. Then I have to check all of those.